# How do I set session timeout of greater than 30 minutes

Tags: jsp, servlets

Dose anybody know how to set session timeout greater than 30 minutes?
these two methods wont work (default to 30 min).

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

and

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(600);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which application server are you using? Tomcat, JBoss, etc.?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat and also want to know how to do it for Glassfish

Comment: A negative time indicates the session should never timeout.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval()

Answer (score 12):

Setting session timeout through the deployment descriptor should work - it sets the default session timeout for the web app. Calling session.setMaxInactiveInterval() sets the timeout for the particular session it is called on, and overrides the default.  Be aware of the unit difference, too - the deployment descriptor version uses minutes, and session.setMaxInactiveInterval() uses seconds.

So

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

sets the default session timeout to 60 minutes.

And

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(600);
```

sets the session timeout to 600 seconds - 10 minutes - for the specific session it's called on.

This should work in Tomcat or Glassfish or any other Java web server - it's part of the spec.

Comment: It truly remains mysterious why framework designers refuse to understand the benefit of using units. A nice framework for working with units is UCUM (http://unitsofmeasure.org).

Answer (score 10):

If you want to never expire a session use `0` or negative value `-1`.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

or mention `1440` it indicates `1440 minutes` [`24hours * 60 minutes`]

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout><!-- 24hours -->
</session-config>
```

Session will be expire after `24hours`.

Answer (score 2):

this will set your session to keep everything till the browser is closed

```
session.setMaxinactiveinterval(-1);
```

and this should set it for 1 day

> session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60*24);

Answer (score 1):

if you are allowed to do it globally then you can set the session time out in

TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml as below

```
 <!-- ==================== Default Session Configuration ================= -->
  <!-- You can set the default session timeout (in minutes) for all newly   -->
  <!-- created sessions by modifying the value below.                       -->


<session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: I think that sets the default for any web apps that don't supply a value - both setting a default for a specific web app in it's deployment descriptor or calling setMaxInactiveInterval on a specific session should override this.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the timeout in the web.xml is the correct way to set the timeout.

Comment: Yes I know that but it won't let me to set session timeout greater than 30 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't let" you? Does it throw and exception? Prevent the server from starting? Pop up an error dialog? Or just appears to not honor the set timeout?

Setting the timeout in the deployment descriptor may require you to restart the web app and/or the server for the new value to take effect.  I don't see what would effect calling setMaxInactiveInterval on a session though... maybe something else is setting setMaxInactiveInterval or invalidating the session?

Comment: @Rocky - Same question as Nate. What do you mean by "won't let me"?

Comment: web.xml/session-config/session-timeout is just the maximum idle time of a session. If the session is idle for a longer time, then the servlet container will throw away any data items associated with the session. Thus if you reach the session by means of a cookie and the cookie has a shorter lifetime, the session is gone from a user perspective while alive from the containers point of view.